# Double Form In 1 page

Tags: php, codeigniter

I wanna ask how can i make my form work correctly
If i click "Tampilkan" i wanna go to laporan_pasien but if i click "Tampilkan PDF" i wanna go to cetakdatapasien

```
<form action="<?=site_url("kepala_poliklinik/laporan_pasien");?>" method="post">
    <form action="<?=site_url("kepala_poliklinik/cetakdatapasien");?>" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Nama : </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nama_h" id="nm_pasien" required>
            <input type="hidden" name="nm_pasien" id="namehidden">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Date range : </label>
            <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-group-addon">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
                </div>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="tgl_kunjungan" id="reservation" required/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-info btn-flat">Tampilkan</button>
        </div>
    </form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-info btn-flat" >Tampilkan PDF</button>
    </div>
</form>
<?php 
if(isset($datapasien)){
    $data["datapasien"]=$datapasien;
    $this->load->view("/kepala/tablepasien",$data);
}?>
```

Comment: Forms are never nested.

Comment: like @SunilPachlangia said there is no nesting of forms.

Comment: i dont know what u mean :/
im still new and learn about php and codeigniter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
<form action="" id="form-submit" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Nama : </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nama_h" id="nm_pasien" required>
        <input type="hidden" name="nm_pasien" id="namehidden">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Date range : </label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-addon">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
            </div>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="tgl_kunjungan" id="reservation" required/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-info btn-flat" id="tampilkan">Tampilkan</button>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-info btn-flat" id="tampilkanpdf">Tampilkan PDF</button>
    </div>
</form>
<?php 
if(isset($datapasien)){
$data["datapasien"]=$datapasien;
$this->load->view("/kepala/tablepasien",$data);
}?>
```

And jQuery code :

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#tampilkan').click(function(){
           $('#form-submit').attr('action', '<?=site_url("kepala_poliklinik/laporan_pasien");?>');
           $('#form-submit').submit();
        });

        $('#tampilkanpdf').click(function(){
           $('#form-submit').attr('action', '<?=site_url("kepala_poliklinik/cetakdatapasien");?>');
           $('#form-submit').submit();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  Use This :-
```

Add Id of Form

```
<form action=""  id="example_form" method="post">
```

Add This code in jquery

```
  var site_url= "www.example.com";

    $('#Tampilkan').click(function(){
       $('#example_form').attr('action', site_url+'/Tampilkan');
    });


    $('#laporan_pasien ').click(function(){
       $('#example_form').attr('action', site_url+'laporan_pasien');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try some thing link this.

```
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Nama : </label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nama_h" id="nm_pasien" required>
                    <input type="hidden" name="nm_pasien" id="namehidden">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Date range : </label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="input-group-addon">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
                        </div>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="tgl_kunjungan" id="reservation" required/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-info btn-flat" onclick="2" name="sample">Tampilkan</button>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-info btn-flat" name="sample1" >Tampilkan PDF</button>
                </div>
            </form>
                <?php 
                if(isset($datapasien)){
                $data["datapasien"]=$datapasien;
                $this->load->view("/kepala/tablepasien",$data);
                }
          if(isset($_REQUEST['sample'])){

                $this->load->view("yourfilename.ext",$data);
                }
              if(isset($_REQUEST['sample1'])){

                $this->load->view("yourfilename1.ext",$data);
                }
          ?>
```